# Detecting subset of high sensitivity corresponding to genotype

Tags: multiple-comparisons, p-value

### Background

There is a data set from a clinical trial, involving about 1000 patients received an behavior intervention. The intervention is supposed to affect a variable x1, and the change in x1 results the change in the response variable y.

The data also contains the information of several(>10) snips for each patient.

### Analysis planned

Given a subset of patients, fit y=beta1*x1+beta2*other variable+…

I would like to find certain combinations of genotype, such that the patients with these genotypes have significantly high beta1.

For each subset (i.e. one geno combination), the p-value of beta1 is calculated and I plan to perform some adjustment to them since all p's are correlated.

What I did below is intended to see if the linear model, with selected variables, is appropriate.

---

### Original question (before comments and edits)

I performed thousands of tests and obtained p-values. Then I did two-sided uniform KS test of the p-values, the result claimed it's uniform. So does it mean that my model are wrong? Because I expect more small p-values near 0.

This is a preliminary step before correcting the multiplicity.

[image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/96546690@N02/9352516904/]

The ks test:

```
One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

D = 0.0493, p-value = 1.388e-06

alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

---

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. 
Doesn't the "p-curve" primarily depend on the number of expected real effects? If you expect that only one out of your 100000 data points will have a small real effect, you would expect an almost uniform distribution over the whole set.
Or did you perform the tests on the same sample with slight variations each time (e.g., permutation tests or the like)?

Comment: I see what you mean. The same test was performed on different subsets of observations, from one data set. The subsets are determined by many possible geno combinations. I do not know what is the proportion that would show an effect. The objective is to identify those subsets with strong effects.

Comment: (1) The KS test indicates the distribution of p-values is *not* uniform. The histogram makes it clear that there is a (slight) tendency towards small p-values. (2) Applying this test is invalid because the results are all strongly interdependent. (3) So, rather than asking a question about a procedure that might be poor or even misleading, why don't you edit your text to (a) provide context for the analysis, (b) state your *scientific* goals, and (c) request suggestions and advice for good statistical procedures to support those goals?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake and the suggestion. I have changed the original post.